# MySQL: Query form two separate ID lists and make one unified list, without duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below and I am trying to merge Block user and block by columns and remove intersect values and create a list of unique numbers, but literally i am failing to get a specific users block list.

```
|------------------------------------------------------
|block_id  | block_user |  block_by  |  block_at
|------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | 22         | 1          | 1434451573
| 7        | 59         | 1          | 1434695298
| 10       | 4          | 1          | 1434695327
| 11       | 1          | 14         | 1434695349
```

I need something as following, it needs to query by the id of 1 ;

```
|-----------
|block_list 
|-----------
| 4
| 14
| 22
| 59
```

I am trying the SQL as following and literally i am failed to get the desired results;

```
SELECT block_user AS blocked_user FROM block_list
UNION 
 SELECT block_by AS blocked_list FROM block_list
WHERE (block_user =  '1' OR block_by =  '1')
```

Comment: Is your expected result right? Don't you want to have the 1 in your block_list too? Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Yes, i don't want the 1,  because i am considering 1 as current user

Comment: Why do you consider 1 as current user? This isn't mentioned in your question? How can I identify which id is the current user in your logic?

Comment: Ionic, if you see my sql, you will be able to see, i am using 1 in the where clause

Comment: Yes sure. But my question was, if it's always 1 as the current user?

Comment: Not always, it may differ based on the auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1 is always to be excluded you can simply use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT block_user as id
    FROM yourTable
    UNION
    SELECT block_by as id
    FROM yourTable
) as dat
WHERE dat.id <> 1
```

Maybe you want to add your `WHERE block_user = 1` to the subquery if it's needed in your logic. This wasn't really clear.

Comment: Sort of getting there, but one issue,  it is returning everything in the table's block_user and block_by Id's

Comment: Yes as mentioned in the answer above, you can filter each of the subqueries too. If you want to filter the `block_by` column, just add the `where` clause as mentioned before under the `from` part. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT block_user
FROM (
     SELECT block_user AS blocked_user FROM block_list
     UNION 
     SELECT block_by AS blocked_user FROM block_list
     WHERE (block_user =  '1' OR block_by =  '1'))
WHERE block_user != '1'
```

Comment: By the way. The `OR` doesn't make sense. If you use to `select block_by` and try where `block_by = 1` and afterwards remove the row which contains = 1, why do you want to get it in the subquery?

Comment: Yes you are right. It doesn't makes sense but i assumed OP might have some logic in there which might be hidden from us hence i used his query as is.

Comment: yes your right, but I just wanted that he is aware of this logical error.